# how to update data in template with out refresh the page in django

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I am working on an eCommerce project. when the user added an item into the cart then item saved into the database then I am reloading the page to update the cart items in the template. but the problem is every time the page reloading is very critical in the production server. so I need help on how to update the data in the template without reloading the page every time. any suggestions, please...
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

you can use ajax in your template. For example

urls.py

```
path(r'ajax/add-product/', add_product, name='search-vendor'),
```

views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def add_product(request):
    data_array = []
    data = request.POST['price']
    ...
    ...
    # do you code  ...
    return JsonResponse(data_array, safe=False)
```

template_name.html

```
<form class="form-inline" id="addproduct-form" name="addproduct-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control r-0 light s-12" name="product_name">
    <input type="text" class="form-control r-0 light s-12" name="product_price">
    ...
    ...
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info search s-12" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
...

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="no-b">
            <th>Product Id</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-content">
    # add your content here
    </tbody>
</table>
....
....
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url: '/ajax/add-product/',
        data : $("#addproduct-form").serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $('.table-content').empty();
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                $(".table-content").append("\
                <tr>\
                <td>"+val['product_id']+"</td>\
                <td>"+val['product_name']+"</td>\
                <td>"+val['price']+"</td>\
                <td>"+val['quantity']+"</td>\
                </tr>\
                ");
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```